# Matplotlib histogram strange additional vertical orange line

Tags: python, matplotlib

I use matplotlib to draw a histogram. The graph looks good; however, an orange line appears on the left side of the graph. I tried to change the dataset, and the line showed every time. In most times it's a straight line, sometimes it's a curve. Could someone tell me what's the meaning of this line? Thanks!

```
plt.figure(figsize=(14,6))
plt.grid(True)
binnum = int(np.rint(np.sqrt(caseNum)))
k = 100
geneNum, caseNum = mcase.shape
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(mcase[:,k], bins=binnum,log=True)
plt.plot(bins)
plt.show()
```

straight:

[image: straight line]

curve:

[image: curved line]

Comment: Please show a self-contained example demonstrating the problem.  You example can't be run because it uses undefined variables like `caseNum` and `mcase`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I'll remember that in the future.

Answer (score 2):

try removing the following line:

```
plt.plot(bins)
```

Answer (score 1):

`plt.hist` already plots the histogram.  You don't need to do `plt.plot(bins)`.  All that is doing is plotting the bin boundary values as a line, giving the line you're seeing.